# Neural network with PROC logistic in SAS

Tags: sas, neural-networks

I am wondering if somebody has used or has any reference to point as to how a neural network in conjunction with PROC logistic can be used in sas. A code would be an ideal thing for me but if unavailable, if somebody can pass me a link as to how can I benefit myself from using neural network alongside logistic ?

Comment: you need EMINER to do the integration...you can either hook them up in a chain, or run the NNET and then group the predictions to make a logit class 2nd stage model

Answer (score 1):

@Ayush Not exactly sure what you mean by using them along side each other? Proc Logistic will not fit a NN. I wonder if you are confusing a logistic activation function in a Neural Net with logistic regression?

In SAS, to my knowledge, you need Enterprise Miner to fit Neural Nets.

Comment: My question is how can you benefit with neural network while applying logistic regression on your dataset. I have used NN in eminer but that doesnt gives me the flexibility or set up to integrate NN with proc logistic. Is there any way we can do it. The intention is to get benefited by NN while doing regression with proc logistic.

Comment: @Ayush. Afraid you lost me on what the integration of these means. Either you could provide a deeper explanation or else perhaps someone else can provide their knowledge.